# Onclick open page and scroll down

Tags: javascript

When particular page is opened by clicking on button which id is "button1", I want that page to be scrolled down.

Could that code be in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

This is the command you can use to scroll down:

```
window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
```

Now if you want to go directly to the bottom you can put this do that while the page are loaded:

```
<body onload="window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);">
```

Comment: I know how to scroll down page, but I don't know how to scroll down page opened by clicking particular button.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what you are asking about:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            clicked(){
                var element = document.getElementById("scrollto");
                element.scrollIntoView();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="clicked()">Click Me</button>

        Your content...





        <div id="scrollto"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

When you click the button, it should scroll down to the div.

If you are asking about navigating to a new page and automatically having it scroll to the right section, you can do something like:

```
<a href="mypage.html#scrollto"></a>
```

and the link will automatically open to that section of the page.

Comment: THANKS!!!! Second part was what I was looking for THANK YOU!!!